# List is still stacking even with Inline display

Tags: css, list

Super new to Front-End development, but doing my best to get better at it by recreating websites that I like from scratch. So far, so good, but for some reason Nav bars are the bane of my existence.

Right now, the Nav links (li's inside of a div) are stacking due to what I can only imagine is a width issue. When I set a certain width, they don't stack anymore, but setting that width restricts me from aligning them to the right with my buttons.

So, what I want to do is have the "logo" div aligned to the left & the "nav_content" div aligned to the right. And when I hit a tablet breakpoint, the "nav_content" div will collapse to a hamburger menu. Hopefully this question makes sense.

Here is my code:

**HTML & CSS**

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ED4C21;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 5px solid #122333;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Khand", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #122333;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  float: left;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.nav_content {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.nav_links {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 22px;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

.nav_links a {
  color: #122333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav_links a:hover {
  color: #ED4C21;
}

.nav_buttons {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 37px;
}

.button {
  font-family: "Khand", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #ED4C21;
}

.button2 {
  margin-left: -2px;
  background-color: #122333;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #ED4C21;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fast Gear</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Fast Gear</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_content">
          <div class="nav_links">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav_buttons">
            <div class="button button1">123-456-7890</div>
            <div class="button button2">Order Online</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to make it with bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set inline links and button so set style='clear:both' for set in same line

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-left: 0;` in your `ul` to get rid of the width problem in this scenario. I would suggest to use bootstrap to have a super responsive web design. If you still want to use your own responsive design use `width` (in %) in all the siblings which need to be in same line. For example width should be mentioned in `%` in both `div.logo` and `div.nav_content`.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ED4C21;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 5px solid #122333;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Khand", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #122333;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  float: left;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.nav_content {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.nav_links {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 22px;
}

.nav_links ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav_links li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

.nav_links a {
  color: #122333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav_links a:hover {
  color: #ED4C21;
}

.nav_buttons {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 37px;
}

.button {
  font-family: "Khand", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #ED4C21;
}

.button2 {
  margin-left: -2px;
  background-color: #122333;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #ED4C21;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fast Gear</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Fast Gear</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_content">
          <div class="nav_links">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav_buttons">
            <div class="button button1">123-456-7890</div>
            <div class="button button2">Order Online</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>



</body>
</html>
```